# How to send spl-tokens with Solana smart contract?

Tags: spl-token, rust, token

I wanted to inquire if anybody knows how to tranfer a spl-token from an account when the account receives a SOL because I'm a novice Rust/Solana developer.

Despite reading the https://docs.solana.com/, I was unable to locate any information about SPL transfers.
I require a website for token minting.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send SPL-Tokens by using CPI on the token program's transfer instruction.

For example:

```
spl_token::instruction::transfer(
  token_program.key,
  source.key,
  destination.key,
  authority.key,
  &[],
  amount,
)?;
invoke_signed(
  &ix,
  &[source, destination, authority, token_program],
  signers,
)
```

You can find a more in depth example by looking at how the token-swap program uses CPI to [transfer spl-tokens](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-swap/program/src/processor.rs#L138-L151)

Answer (score 1):

Go through the SPL Token Section of the CookBook and you can find your answers
[there](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#what-do-i-need-to-get-started-with-spl-tokens) tag me here if you still dont get your answer's